# The things you wish you would have done before doing a PhD in Organic Chemistry?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, synthesis

Hello there fellow chemists. I am really interested in doing a PhD in Organic chemistry. I haven't really thought which field I would like to specialize in, but it's definitely on my mind ever since spending a considerable amount of time in the lab during my fourth year research project (note: I am doing a 4 year MSci). I've always had a liking towards Organic chemistry compared to Inorganic and Physical. Apart from my department I haven't been able to find much general information regarding procedures and routes available. I understand that doing a PhD means dedicating 3 or 4 years of your life to research and even though nothing is guaranteed one needs to be prepared and have insight before embarking on a journey.

Please feel free to share your thoughts and comments

Thanks

Comment: This question might be more suitable for https://academia.stackexchange.com

Comment: @ManRow Probably not suitable enough...